# Как отправить сообщение больше 1024 символов в embed

Tags: python, discord

Как мне вывести оставшийся текст вторым add_field?

```
   @commands.Cog.listener()
   async def on_message(self, message):
       timestamp = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(r'Europe/Moscow'))
       channel = self.bot.get_channel(1111)
       whitelist1 = ['1) запрещен capslock']
       num_of_fields = len(message.content)
       if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot and (len(list(filter (lambda x : x in message.content.lower(), whitelist1))) > 0):
               embedVar = nextcord.Embed(title="⚡️  ⚡️", description=message.author.mention, color=0xFFFFE0)
       for i in range(num_of_fields):
               embedVar.add_field(name="Правила Discord сервера ", value=f'{message.content[i*1024:i+1*1024]}', inline=True)
               embedVar.set_footer(text=f'Технический администратор дискорд сервера. \u200b{timestamp}', icon_url="https://cdn.nextcordapp.com/avatars/706621027953672253/3fcb6700f5e6fccb8e9e46b720c26208.png") 
               await message.delete()            
               await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```